# How to solve this problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

A ball is projected vertically upward with a speed of $ 50 $ m/s , I need to find out the speed at half the maximum height.

What i have done,

Found the maximum height by $ H = \frac{u^2}{2g} $ and got it 125 m. I putted $ s = \frac{125}{2} $ in the equation $ s = ut - ½gt^2 $

Then, after putting $ u = 50 m/s , g = 10 m/s^2 $ i got two values of time as $ t = 5 ±  \frac{5\sqrt{2}}{2} $ .

I am totally confused at this stage, what to do.....
Any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I agree with all the values you've obtained so far. From this point on you need to put down a list of all the values you have, and the value you need. What you want to find is $v$, and to do that we already have the values for $s$, $u$ and $t$. From this we can think of what SUVAT equation links all three. The equation $$s = (\frac{u + v}{2})t$$ works in this situation. Rearranging this equation to make $v$ to subject we get $$v = \frac{2s}{t} - u$$ From this point you can plug in your values obtained so far and solve :)

Think about which value of $t$ you want to use, however!

> It depends on whether you want it to be the speed coming up, or coming down.

Answer (score 1):

When a projectile is thrown vertically upwards, it crosses a certain height (between the maximum height and point of projection) exactly twice.

The projectile will reach a height 'h' when going up to the maximum height and again when coming down.

So, you will get two values of time. If you need to find the value of the speed at a certain height, I suggest you to use this formula,

$v^2=u^2+2as$